# Out-Degree of a Configuration Graph

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

In Chapter 4 in Computational Complexity by Arora and Barak it states, regarding the configuration graph of a Turing Machine, that

> If M is deterministic, then the
> graph has out-degree one, and if M is nondeterministic, then the graph has out-degree
> at most two.

In the configuration graph, a directed edge is placed from the configurations $C$ to $C'$ if we can obtain $C'$ from $C$ via a single transition. Also, the authors assume we are working with two tape Turing machine with one read-only input tape and one read-write work tape. Here, the authors define a configuration by

> A configuration of a TM M
> consists of the contents of all nonblank entries of M’s tapes, along with its state and head
> position, at a particular point in its execution.

I understand that the out-degree for a deterministic machine must be 1, but I do not see why the out-degree for the non-deterministic machine can be at most 2. Given that the authors assume that $\Gamma= \{0,1\}$, I would assume that the number of possible configurations reachable from any given configuration would be $|\Gamma||Q||\{L,R\}^2|$ for a two tape Turing machine, where $Q$ is the set of states and one head is on a read-only input tape. Why would the out-degree of this graph be at most $2$ instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some research into other things related to TMs, I discovered that any NDTM that has at most $k$ possible branches at each step can be modified into an NDTM that has at most $2$ possible branches at each step at the cost of a $\log_2(k)$ slowdown. Though I can not find any mention of this anywhere in the textbook, I assume this is what the authors are assuming.

Comment: Exactly. However, even if we do not assume this, a constant bound on the out-degree of the configuration graph seems good enough for most purposes (such as, as a minor detail in the proof of Savitch's Theorem).